Connectivity Issues with Android IoT Device Inside RF Shield Box: Troubleshooting and Potential Causes
We are experiencing connectivity issues with an Android IoT device when it is connected inside an RF shield box. The setup involves connecting the Android device to a USB port inside the RF shield box, which then connects to a PC via an external USB port. Direct connection of the Android device to the PC works fine, but communication fails when the device is connected through the RF shield box.
We have already considered the below things:
USB Cable Quality
USB Port Integrity
Signal Interference
Connection Stability
Power Supply
Driver and Software
Cable Length
Are there any good usb cables that work fine at longer lengths?
We want a stable and fast connection

Possibly more appropriate: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=usb%20cable&searchOn=3
